# android posting to php not working correctly

Tags: php, android

I have an android app that posts data to a php webservice, if it posts from the android app to  the php webserive it doesn't work as expected, if the same data is posted to the php webservice from a html page it works correctly.

The part of the php script that doesn't work is the following:

```
function makeThumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

/* read the source image */ 
$imgsrc =   explode('.',$src,-1);
$imgdest    =   explode('.',$dest,-1);
$dest   =   $imgdest[0].'Thumb.png';
$source_image = imageConvert($src, $dest,0);



list($width, $height, $img_type, $img_attr) = getimagesize($dest);

//$width = imagesx($source_image);
//$height = imagesy($source_image);

/* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
$desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

/* create a new, "virtual" image */

$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

imagealphablending($virtual_image, false);
/* copy source image at a resized size */
$source_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
//imagealphablending($source_image, false);

imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

/* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
imagealphablending($virtual_image,false);
imagesavealpha($virtual_image,true);
imagepng($virtual_image, $dest);

}
```

The code that posts to the php file from android is this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    // ::

    File tempFile = getTempFile();

    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + TEMP_PHOTO_FILE;
    System.out.println("path " + filePath);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

    // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); // compress to
                                                            // which format
                                                            // you want.
    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "uploadImage"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sociochatU",
            IMService.USERNAME));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sociochatP",
            IMService.password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mpf",
            "true"));

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        SocketOperator.AUTHENTICATION_SERVER + "includes/inc.upload.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                final String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this,
                                "Response " + the_string_response,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (final Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Error in http connection "
                        + e.toString());
            }
        }

    });

    t.start();

}
```

The code I used in HTML to post to the same php file is the followig:

```
<form method="POST" action="SocketOperator.AUTHENTICATION_SERVER & "includes/inc.upload.php" target="_blank">

<input name="sociochatU" id="sociochatU" value=""/><br/>
    <input name="sociochatP" id="sociochatP" value=""/><br/>
    <input name="mpf" id="mpf" value="true"/><br/>
<textarea name="image" id="base64"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
```

I have no idea what the problem could be, any suggestions?

Comment: So what _is_ actually posted? Did you check? And what does the http servers error log file say? You are currently _guessing_ what might happen. Look and read instead.

Comment: @arkascha What happens is that it does actually post the base64 code to the server, a image is create on server side with both the android app and the html code. BUT, only the html code is creating the THUMB, the android one however doesn't. What makes me so confused is that the php file is doing all the work, the other 2 is just posting the image. However, there is nothing in the errorlog file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem right after posting the code here.

I noticed that the android app was compressing the image to a PNG image, and on the server side it was assigning it as a JPG file, changed the code on the php file to rather assign a PNG extension and voila. It worked.